# Unix untar and Retain File Permissions

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script that will unpack a .tgz file and put the new files in the root directory.

Is it possible to add an argument to the line below so that the new files will retain the file permissions of the original files that are being overwritten?

```
tar xf /install/newfiles/files.tgz -C /
```

Comment: `Is it possible ... retain the file permissions of the original files that are being overwritten?` -- **NO**.

Comment: Ah - so not like an FTP where it can overwrite the files but remember what file permission it had.

Comment: On a second thought, if your `tar` supports the `--overwrite` option, it might do what you're looking for.

Comment: you could write a little script that stored the permissions and then restored them after the untar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this for future reference.  Thanks to @devnull and @Vorsprung for their comments.

`Is it possible to add an argument to the line below so that the new files will retain the file permissions of the original files that are being overwritten?`

**Answer:** Simple answer is NO, but the `tar` command can support the `--overwrite` option (test this before use).

***Second option*** is to create a shell script that can be run that will CHMOD the files after the new files have been put in their place.